# How can I sign my Bundle App in android studio for AppGallery?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I signed the Bundle app and exported Public.jks and private.pepk keys.

When I update the published App with app.aab on AppGallery console, tt says the app is not signed but when I upload the app-release.apk it accepts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To publish your app in AAB format you must configure the AGC app signing service

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-app_bundle